# Equivalent conditions of weak differentiability

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory, weak-derivatives

Let

- $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$
- $T>0$
- $E$ be a $\mathbb R$-Banach space
- $u,v\in L^1_{\text{loc}}((0,T),E)$

In *Navier-Stokes Equations: Theory and Numerical Analysis* by *Roger Temam* I've read in [Lemma 1.1 of Chapter III](https://books.google.de/books?id=CKYJBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA169&lpg=PA169&dq=%22temam%22+%22lemma+1.1%22+%22the+following+three+conditions+are+equivalent%22&source=bl&ots=0pxKTWhZQn&sig=Ih58P42gpZHLRUfKYWm6Xv_TkXs&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwin5oiguYTPAhVDmBoKHZSTBRgQ6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=%22temam%22%20%22lemma%201.1%22%20%22the%20following%20three%20conditions%20are%20equivalent%22&f=false) that the following statements are equivalent:

1. $u\in W^1((0,T),E)$ with $u'=v$
2. Let $\eta\in E'$ $\Rightarrow$ $$\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}\langle\eta(u)\rangle_{\mathcal D'((0,T))}=\langle\eta(v)\rangle_{\mathcal D'((0,T))}\tag 1$$

where $W^1((0,T),E)$ is the set of $L^1_{\text{loc}}((0,T),E)$-functions which admit a weak derivative in $L^1_{\text{loc}}((0,T),E)$ and $$\langle f\rangle_{\mathcal D'((0,T))}(\phi):=\int_{(0,\:T)}\phi f\;{\rm d}\lambda$$ denotes the distribution generated by $f\in L^1_{\text{loc}}((0,T),E)$.

---

> I wonder why he is taking the derivative in 2. in the distributional sense. If I'm not terribly wrong, we should have $\eta(u)\in W^1((0,T))$ for all $\eta\in E'$, if $u\in W^1((0,T),E)$.

Assume that 1. holds and let $\eta\in E'$. In fact, it's easy to see that $$\eta(u)\in L^1_{\text{loc}}((0,T))\;.\tag 2$$ Now, we should have

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
-\int_{(0,\:T)}\phi\eta(v)\;{\rm d}\lambda&=-\int_{(0,\:T)}\eta(\phi v)\;{\rm d}\lambda\\
&=\eta\left(-\int_{(0,\:T)}\phi v\;{\rm d}\lambda\right)\\
&=\eta\left(\int_{(0,\:T)}\phi'u\;{\rm d}\lambda\right)\\
&=\int_{(0,\:T)}\eta(\phi'u)\;{\rm d}\lambda\\
&=\int_{(0,\:T)}\phi'\eta(u)\;{\rm d}\lambda
\end{split}\tag 3
\end{equation}

So, 1. and 2. should be equivalent to

3. Let $\eta\in E'$ $\Rightarrow$ $\eta(u)\in W^1((0,T))$ with $$\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}\eta(u)=\eta(v)\tag 4$$

too. Am I wrong?